# How to prevent mu4e from checking mail when the internet is down?

Tags: email, mu4e, imap

**Q:** how do I prevent `mu4e` from automatically checking mail
when the internet's down?

#### Problem

I use `mu4e` and `offlineimap` to handle my email.  When on a
laptop, I have to deal with the fact that I sometimes have spotty
wifi connections.  `offlineimap` freaks out when it gets called
without an internet connection.

#### Problem as it relates to `mu4e`

I have `mu4e` invoke `offlineimap` automatically every 5 minutes
or so:

```
(setq mu4e-get-mail-command "offlineimap -o"
      mu4e-update-interval  300)
```

Unfortunately, that means it doesn't check if I've actually got an
internet connection.

#### So...

How do I tell `mu4e` not to invoke `offlineimap` if there's no
internet connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use wrapper shell script.

Below please find trivial sample script checking connection status as reported by Unix/Linux NetworkManager.

```
#!/bin/sh
# exit if there is no internet connection
/usr/bin/nm-online || exit 

/usr/bin/offlineimap -o
```

Emacs fix (use wrapper instead of directly using offlineimap):

```
(setq mu4e-get-mail-command "/home/me/bin/offlineimap-wrapper.sh"
      mu4e-update-interval  300)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm on Linux so this works for me, but I'm going to leave the post open for a little longer to see if there are any OS-agnostic ways to do it.

Answer (score 5):

*(Posting this Q&A combo since it took me a while to figure out, and it might save someone else the trouble.)*

Based on
[this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/elisp-code-to-check-for-internet-connection/18515#18515) to
a question on how to test for an internet connection within elisp,
we can call a shell command:

```
(defun internet-up-p (&optional host)
  (= 0 (call-process "ping" nil nil nil "-c" "1" "-W" "1" 
                     (if host host "www.google.com"))))
```

We can then add advice to the relevant `mu4e` function to tell it
to do its thing only if there's a connection:

```
(advice-add #'mu4e-update-mail-and-index
            :before-while
            (lambda (&rest args)
              (internet-up-p)))
```