# Recurrent pop-up when queued email sends without internet connection

Tags: mu4e

I use `mu4e` and [`mu4e-send-delay`](https://github.com/bandresen/mu4e-send-delay/). When I send a message immediately and don't have an internet connection, I see this message in the mini-buffer:

```
smtp.domain.tld/25 nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

The message remains open in the Emacs frame with some changes such as the FCC header with the destination filepath and is saved to Drafts.

When I delay sending mail with `mu4e-send-delay`, at the time of sending, the mini-buffer shows `Sending via mail...`. If I have no internet connection at the time of sending, a pop-up appears in Emacs:

```
Emacs-x86_64-10_14

Buffer *temp* modified; kill anyway?

[Yes] [No]
```

If I click `Yes`, the mini-buffer changes to `Buffer *temp* modified; kill anyway? y`. If I click `No`, the mini-buffer changes to `Buffer *temp* modified; kill anyway? n` and I get a file similar to `*message*-20190627-105554` saved in the home directory with the content of the message:

```
User-agent: mu4e 1.2.0; emacs 26.2
From: ...
To: ...
Subject: ...
Fcc: /path/to/maildir/Sent Items/cur/1561629089.e6e765d7b4ad6364.hostname:2,S
Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2019 11:01:54 +0100
Message-ID: <some-id.fsf@domain.tld>
--text follows this line--
...
```

Annoyingly, I get a new saved message with the same content every time I click `No` in the Emacs pop-up.

How can I avoid these annoying pop-ups every time the queue timer runs without an internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

#### tl;dr

Use [my fork](https://github.com/miguelmorin/mu4e-send-delay) instead, which tests for an internet connection before sending each message.

#### Details

I played with the source code and the issue is in the function [`mu4e-send-delay-send-if-due`](https://github.com/bandresen/mu4e-send-delay/blob/master/mu4e-send-delay.el), which calls `(message-send-mail)` on line 258. The help for this last function shows:

```
message-send-mail is a compiled Lisp function in ‘message.el’.
```

and its source code modifies the buffer and then calls `kill-buffer` without options for confirmation.

```
(defun message-send-mail (&optional _)
    ...
    (kill-buffer tembuf))
    ...
    )
```

My solution was to check for an internet connection before trying to send each message. I could have done that check at function `mu4e-send-delay-send-queue`, but if the client has no internet connection but also no messages to send, I didn't want to print a message when the queue timer ran. So I put it in the function that tries to send the message instead at the cost of printing a new message on the mini-buffer for each message in the queue. I used the internet check [from here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/elisp-code-to-check-for-internet-connection/18515#18515):

```
(defcustom mu4e-internet-host-test "www.gnu.org"
  "Host to test internet connection before sending mail."
  :type 'string
  :group 'mu4e-delay)


(defun mu4e-internet-up-p (&optional host)
  "Test if internet connection is up (default host is defined by custom variable
mu4e-internet-host-test."
  (= 0 (call-process "ping" nil nil nil "-c" "1" "-W" "1" 
             (if host host mu4e-internet-host-test))))

(defun mu4e-send-delay-send-if-due (mail-file-path)
  "Send mail when MAIL-FILE-PATH contains scheduled time earlier
than current time and is not currently being edited."
  (when (and (mu4e-send-delay-elapsed-p mail-file-path)
             (not (mu4e-send-delay-file-buffer-open mail-file-path)))
    (if (not (mu4e-internet-up-p))
    (message "mu4e: unable to send queued message for lack of internet connection")
    ... ;; same code as before, with an extra parenthesis
    (error "mu4e-send: %s" err)))))
```

I filed [an issue](https://github.com/bandresen/mu4e-send-delay/issues/19) and proposed [a pull request with this fix](https://github.com/bandresen/mu4e-send-delay/pull/20) but the repo seems inactive. If the pull request is not merged, use [my fork instead](https://github.com/miguelmorin/mu4e-send-delay).